# jquery order of elements

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

```
    <ul id="box">
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">2</li>
    </ul>

    $("#box").sortable({ update: function() {
    var order = $("#box").sortable("serialize");
    alert(order);
    }
   });
```

How to get the very same result in order variable without using sortable?

Comment: i do not get u what u r saying?. how output should be like? from -> to

Answer (score 0):

chang `<ul> to <ol>`, because ul means unsortable list

Comment: i want to get the order without sortable